# How to create subset groups by identifying unique strings within column names

Tags: group-by, subset

I have a dataframe:

```
`df <- data.frame(Year = 1940:2000, 
             sp99_002_04A_01 = rnorm(61, 1:100), 
             sp99_002_04B_01 = rnorm(61, 1:100), 
             sp99_002_05A_01 = rnorm(61, 1:100),
             sp99_006_01A_14 = rnorm(61, 1:100),
             sp99_023a_02B_06 = rnorm(61, 1:100),
             sp99_023a_05B_06 = rnorm(61, 1:100),
             sp99_010_03B_03 = rnorm(61, 1:100))`
```

Each name is formatted: speciesyear_plot#(subset)_sample#_trial#, as shown above.

I need to group columns for further analysis by plot number. That means all columns sharing the same unique character string in xxxx_THIS_xxxx_xx location of the column names, without having to call each plot # by name.

Comment: Consider reshaping your data from wide to long format (i.e., [tidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html)) to retain one *sample* column and then grouping is so much easier! As is aggregation, merging, plotting, modeling, etc.

Comment: Also, per `r` tag, please use `dput` to show data (which is much easier to comprehend than telling us the data).

Comment: Is there an easy way to separate my current column names into individual columns?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
'mydt <- fread("data.csv")

mydt <- melt.data.table(mydt, id.vars = "Year", value.name = 'measure', variable.name 
= "ID")
mydt <- na.omit(mydt)
mydt[, ID := as.character(ID)]

splitNames <- lapply(mydt$ID, FUN = function(x) {

splitUpID <- strsplit(x, split = "_")
plot <- splitUpID[[1]][2]

return(plot)
})
plots <- unlist(splitNames)
mydt[, plot := plots]'
```